# unzip a file using Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, unzip, jenkins-groovy

I have a zip file with name ***.zip. I used below command to unzip it. Once I unzip, the files inside them are also "Zip" files(More than 3 zip files). Could you please let me know how can I unzip even these files as well.

```
unzip zipFile: "$project_version",dir:"D:\\jenkins\\DEV\\extract\\project", quiet: true
```

Trying to do-

```
unzip dir: 'D:\\jenkins\\DEV\\extract\\project', glob: '', zipFile: 'D:\\jenkins\\DEV\\extract\\project\\project_*.zip'
```

Error Logs

```
java.io.IOException: D:\jenkins\DEV\extract\project\project_*.zip does not exist.
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.zip.UnZipStepExecution.run(UnZipStepExecution.java:77)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:260)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Files under my directory after I unzip the main zip file.

```
05/16/2018  04:31 PM    <DIR>          .
05/16/2018  04:31 PM    <DIR>          ..
05/15/2018  12:51 PM           265,637 project-project1_1.0.0.24_bdd86e0c.zip
05/15/2018  12:51 PM         7,924,188 project-project2_1.4.0.130_43dce5e4.zip
05/15/2018  12:51 PM         6,862,842 project-project3_1.0.0.207_c7d5d471.zip
               3 File(s)     15,052,667 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  432,451,330,048 bytes free
```

I need similar command in windows-

```
for file in `ls 123_*.zip'; do unzip $file -d `echo $file | cut -d "." -f 1`; done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

function Unzip
{
    param([string]$zipfile, [string]$outpath)
    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($zipfile, $outpath)
}

Unzip "C:\Temp\Powershell\Test.zip" "C:\Temp\Powershell\"
$DirName =  Get-ChildItem "C:\Temp\Powershell\Test"

foreach ( $item in $DirName){
    Unzip "C:\Temp\Powershell\Test\$item" "C:\Temp\Powershell\Test\"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use pipeline utility step in the steps block
should work with both scripted and declarative styles of pipeline

```
steps {
      unzip zipFile: 'file.zip', dir: '<directory>'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bat 'for /R . %I in ("*.zip") do ( "C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe" x -y -o"%~dpnI" "%~fI" )'
```

We can use this under Jenkins pipeline script to achieve above requirement

Comment: it has not much (except, that its a bat step) to do with a jnekinsfile...